# Attribute error while using Wordnet API with python 2.7.3

Tags: python-2.7, wordnet, corpus

I installed `nltk` using pip install on python 2.7.3. When I run these commands

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
dog = wn.sysnet('dog.n.01')
```

I get the following error ..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 71, in __getattr__
return getattr(self, attr)
AttributeError: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'sysnet'
```

How should I correct it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want `word.synset`, not `word.sysnet`

[nltk documentation for synset](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html#synset).